# add quantity of value if that value exists in array fuction in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I'm having a problem with writing code that is used for payment for books.
It have to add quantity if ISBN number is the same, but it doesn't add quantity and it makes another value that has same ISBN... I can't figure out how can I add quantity in the existing value. I think the problem is in the `searchinventory` function, or `addbook` itself.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_BOOKS 10
#define MAX_TITLE_SIZE 20

struct Book {
    int _isbn; //International Standard Book Number
    float _price; //Book Price
    int _year; // Publication Year
    char _title[MAX_TITLE_SIZE]; //Book Title
    int _qty; //Book Quantity
};
//////////////////////////////////
void flushKeyboard(void);
void displayInventory(const struct Book book[],const int size);
void addBook(struct Book book[],int *size);
int searchInventory(const struct Book book[],const int isbn,const int size);
void checkPrice(const struct Book book[],const int size);
///////////////////////////////////
void flushKeyboard(void)
{
    char enter;
    do{
        scanf("%c",&enter);


    }while(enter != '\n');
}
void displayInventory(const struct Book book[],const int size){
    int i = 0;
    printf("\n\nInventory\n");
    printf("===================================================\n");
    printf("ISBN      Title               Year Price  Quantity\n");
    printf("---------+-------------------+----+-------+--------\n");

    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
            printf("%-10.0d%-20s%-5d$%-8.2f%-8d\n",book[i]._isbn,book[i]._title,book[i]._year,book[i]._price,book[i]._qty);
    }
    printf("===================================================\n\n");
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////
void addBook(struct Book book[],int *size){
    int result = -1;
    int _isbn;
    int _qty;

    if(*size == MAX_BOOKS){
        printf("the inventory is full");

    }

    else{
        printf("ISBN:");

        scanf("%d",&_isbn);
        result = searchInventory(&book[*size],_isbn,*size);

        printf("_isbn = %d\n",_isbn);
        printf("Quantity:");

        scanf("%d",&_qty);

        if(result != -1){
            book[result]._isbn = _isbn;
            book[result]._qty = book[result]._qty + _qty;
            printf("The book exists in the repository, quantity is updated.\n");

            printf("book[result]._qty is %d\n",book[result]._qty);
            printf("book[*size]._qty is %d\n",book[*size]._qty);
            }
        if(result == -1){
            book[*size]._isbn = _isbn;
            book[*size]._qty = _qty;
            printf("Title:");

            scanf(" %20[^\n]",book[*size]._title);
            flushKeyboard();
            printf("Year:");
            scanf("%d",&book[*size]._year);
            printf("Price:");
            scanf("%f",&book[*size]._price);
            printf("The book is successfully added to the inventory.\n\n");

        }
        }
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int searchInventory(const struct Book book[],const int isbn,const int size){
    int i = 0;
    int result = -1;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        if(isbn == (book[i]._isbn)){

            result = i;
            return result;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void checkPrice(const struct Book book[],const int size){
    int isbn;
    int i = 0;

    printf("Please input the ISBN number of the book\n\n");
    scanf("%d",&isbn);

    i = searchInventory(&book[size],isbn,size);

    printf("Book %d costs %.2d\n\n",isbn,book[size]._price);
}
int main(void){

    struct Book book[MAX_BOOKS];
    int size=0;
    int option;
    printf("Welcome to the Book Store\n=========================\n");
    do{

        printf("Please select from the following options:\n");
        printf("1) Display the inventory.\n");
        printf("2) Add a book to the inventory.\n");
        printf("3) Check price.\n");
        printf("0) Exit.\n");

        printf("\nSelect: ");
        scanf("%d",&option);
        switch(option){
            case 1:
                if(size == 0){
                    printf("The inventory is empty!\n");
                    printf("===================================================\n\n");

                }
                else{
                        displayInventory(book,size);
                }

                break;
            case 2:
            //SIZE++;
            addBook(book,&size);
            size++;
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("Please select input the ISBN number of the book: \n\n");
                //checkPrice();
                break;
            case 0:
                printf("Goodbye!\n");
                break;
            default: //wrong input
                printf("Invalid input, try again:\n");
                break;
        }
    }while(option!=0);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is your debugging effort?

Comment: 1) `result = searchInventory(&book[*size],_isbn,*size);` --> `result = searchInventory(book,_isbn,*size);`

Comment: 2) `printf("book[*size]._qty is %d\n",book[*size]._qty);` : `book[*size]._qty` has not been set yet.

Comment: searchInventory(&book[0],isbn,*size); OR searchInventory(book,isbn,*size);

Comment: And, please, do `size++` only in case if you add a really new book, but not just add quantity to an existing one

Comment: 3) `printf("Book %d costs %.2d\n\n",isbn,book[size]._price);` --> `printf("Book %d costs %.2f\n\n",isbn,book[i]._price);`

Comment: 4) ISBN code need `int64_t`. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number)

Comment: 5) `scanf(" %20[^\n]",book[*size]._title);` --> `scanf(" %19[^\n]",book[*size]._title);`

Comment: A (C) developer should be able to use appropriate debuggers. Nice reading here: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

Please try if the following code can help you. I have tried to fix the errors so that adding a new book counts up the number of that particular book in the bookstore.

Test run the program:

```
Welcome to the Book Store
=========================
Please select from the following options:
1) Display the inventory.
2) Add a book to the inventory.
3) Check price.
0) Exit.

Select: 1
The inventory is empty!
===================================================

Please select from the following options:
1) Display the inventory.
2) Add a book to the inventory.
3) Check price.
0) Exit.

Select: 2
ISBN:12345678
_isbn = 12345678
Quantity:2
Title:FOO
Year:1991
Price:19
The book is successfully added to the inventory.

Please select from the following options:
1) Display the inventory.
2) Add a book to the inventory.
3) Check price.
0) Exit.

Select: 1


Inventory
===================================================
ISBN      Title               Year Price  Quantity
---------+-------------------+----+-------+--------
12345678  FOO                 1991 $19.00   2       
===================================================

Please select from the following options:
1) Display the inventory.
2) Add a book to the inventory.
3) Check price.
0) Exit.

Select: 2
ISBN:87654321
_isbn = 87654321
Quantity:1
Title:BAZ
Year:1987
Price:4
The book is successfully added to the inventory.

Please select from the following options:
1) Display the inventory.
2) Add a book to the inventory.
3) Check price.
0) Exit.

Select: 1


Inventory
===================================================
ISBN      Title               Year Price  Quantity
---------+-------------------+----+-------+--------
12345678  FOO                 1991 $19.00   2       
87654321  BAZ                 1987 $4.00    1       
===================================================

Please select from the following options:
1) Display the inventory.
2) Add a book to the inventory.
3) Check price.
0) Exit.

Select: 2
ISBN:12345678
_isbn = 12345678
Quantity:3
The book exists in the repository, quantity is updated.
book[result]._qty is 5
Please select from the following options:
1) Display the inventory.
2) Add a book to the inventory.
3) Check price.
0) Exit.

Select: 1


Inventory
===================================================
ISBN      Title               Year Price  Quantity
---------+-------------------+----+-------+--------
12345678  FOO                 1991 $19.00   5       
87654321  BAZ                 1987 $4.00    1       
===================================================

Please select from the following options:
1) Display the inventory.
2) Add a book to the inventory.
3) Check price.
0) Exit.

Select:
```

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define MAX_BOOKS 10
#define MAX_TITLE_SIZE 20

struct Book {
    int64_t _isbn; //International Standard Book Number
    float _price; //Book Price
    int _year; // Publication Year
    char _title[MAX_TITLE_SIZE]; //Book Title
    int _qty; //Book Quantity
};
//////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////
void flushKeyboard(void);
void displayInventory(const struct Book book[],const int size);
int addBook(struct Book book[],int *size);
int searchInventory(const struct Book book[],const int isbn,const int size);
void checkPrice(const struct Book book[],const int size);
///////////////////////////////////
void flushKeyboard(void)
{
    char enter;
    do{
        scanf("%c",&enter);


    }while(enter != '\n');
}
void displayInventory(const struct Book book[],const int size){
    int i = 0;
    printf("\n\nInventory\n");
    printf("===================================================\n");
    printf("ISBN      Title               Year Price  Quantity\n");
    printf("---------+-------------------+----+-------+--------\n");

    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        printf("%-10.0d%-20s%-5d$%-8.2f%-8d\n",book[i]._isbn,book[i]._title,book[i]._year,book[i]._price,book[i]._qty);
    }
    printf("===================================================\n\n");
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////
int addBook(struct Book book[],int *size){
    int result = -1;
    int _isbn;
    int _qty;

    if(*size == MAX_BOOKS){
        printf("the inventory is full");

    }

    else{
        printf("ISBN:");

        scanf("%d",&_isbn);
        result = searchInventory(book,_isbn,*size);
        printf("_isbn = %d\n",_isbn);
        printf("Quantity:");

        scanf("%d",&_qty);

        if(result != -1){
            book[result]._isbn = _isbn;
            book[result]._qty = book[result]._qty + _qty;
            printf("The book exists in the repository, quantity is updated.\n");

            printf("book[result]._qty is %d\n",book[result]._qty);
            //printf("book[*size]._qty is %d\n",book[*size]._qty);
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            book[*size]._isbn = _isbn;
            book[*size]._qty = _qty;
            printf("Title:");

            scanf(" %19[^\n]",book[*size]._title);
            flushKeyboard();
            printf("Year:");
            scanf("%d",&book[*size]._year);
            printf("Price:");
            scanf("%f",&book[*size]._price);
            printf("The book is successfully added to the inventory.\n\n");
            return 1;

        }
    }
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int searchInventory(const struct Book book[],const int isbn,const int size){
    int i = 0;
    int result = -1;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        if(isbn == (book[i]._isbn)){

            result = i;
            return result;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void checkPrice(const struct Book book[],const int size){
    int isbn;
    int i = 0;

    printf("Please input the ISBN number of the book\n\n");
    scanf("%d",&isbn);

    i = searchInventory(&book[size],isbn,size);

    printf("Book %d costs %.2f\n\n",isbn,book[i]._price);
}
int main(void){

    struct Book book[MAX_BOOKS];
    int size=0;
    int option;
    printf("Welcome to the Book Store\n=========================\n");
    do{

        printf("Please select from the following options:\n");
        printf("1) Display the inventory.\n");
        printf("2) Add a book to the inventory.\n");
        printf("3) Check price.\n");
        printf("0) Exit.\n");

        printf("\nSelect: ");
        scanf("%d",&option);
        switch(option){
            case 1:
                if(size == 0){
                    printf("The inventory is empty!\n");
                    printf("===================================================\n\n");

                }
                else{
                    displayInventory(book,size);
                }

                break;
            case 2:
                //SIZE++;
                size = size + addBook(book,&size);
                //size++;
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("Please select input the ISBN number of the book: \n\n");
                //checkPrice();
                break;
            case 0:
                printf("Goodbye!\n");
                break;
            default: //wrong input
                printf("Invalid input, try again:\n");
                break;
        }
    }while(option!=0);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is necessary to return the value in `if(*size == MAX_BOOKS){  }`. However, it is not necessary to change the return type of the function to `int`. Let it be `++*size;` or `*size += 1;` instead of `return 1;`.